# Dompdf php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Buenas, una vez que aplique el dompdf, me funciona perfecto,a la hora de imprimir notas de clientes hace el salgo de pagina, y cada hoja tiene su encabezado.
Mi problema es que cuando una nota de cliente supera una hoja, ahi no aparece el encabezado y quiero que lo haga. Que etiqueta deberia de usar? o que funcion?
Espero que me haga entender. Desde ya muchas gracias. 
el salto de pagina lo hago con:

```
<table style="page-break-after:always;"></table>
```